# How to collect stats with StatsD?

Tags: metrics, graphing, statsd

So, the one thing I do not understand from the Etsy StatsD documentation is how to get useful metrics sent from StatsD.

I understand that you can send metrics by:

```
echo "service.test.random:1|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125
```

But, do I wrap a bunch of metrics I want to use in a bash cron job? Do I use the files located in /install/location/statsd/lib/ as basic metrics to get the process going? If so, do they just run? Do I add a flag in the config to pick up these files?

I am a bit confused on getting StatsD working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You usually send stats using a statsd client from a running application. For example, increment a counter every time a user buys a product, set timers for the different views. This way metrics are sent in "real time" from the application, and you can later inspect them (and their rollups) in Graphite.

Check the [list of available clients](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/wiki#client-implementations).

Comment: Now, I was told that the etsy statsd was a server AND a client - but is that true? Because maybe that is the root of my misunderstanding.

Comment: You can send metrics to the statsd server using `echo + `nc`, but usually it is easier to use a client library. Also, as you can see at https://github.com/etsy/statsd/wiki, the Py-Statsd implementation includes both the client and the server.